# Can Gradle precompiled scripts plugins use java-gradle-plugin?

Tags: java, gradle

(Gradle version `7.3.3`)

I'm following [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins)
regarding the gradle precompiled scripts plugins.

1. Plugin to use

The `groovy-gradle-plugin` is used in this case.
I tried with the `java-gradle-plugin`but it doesn't seem to generate the plugin classes.
Is this to be expected?

2. Plugins id's

Following the documentation:

> src/main/groovy/my.java-library-convention.gradle would result in a
> plugin ID of my.java-library-convention.

I want to prefix my scripts with: `com.mycompany.myproject.conventions-java-library`
In this case, the generated plugin classes are named with this full name in the default package.
Is this to be expected?
I expected to find a class named `JavaLibraryPlugin`generated in the `com.mycompany.myproject.conventions`package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The groovy-gradle-plugin is used in this case. I tried with the java-gradle-plugin but it doesn't seem to generate the plugin classes. Is this to be expected?

Not fully sure what you are asking.
If you meant applying the `java-gradle-plugin` instead of the `groovy-gradle-plugin`, this of course will not produce any plugin classes. How should the Java plugin know about Groovy source files?

Why I'm not sure whether that is what you asked is, because the `groovy-gradle-plugin` already automatically applies the `java-gradle-plugin`. So if you want to use Groovy DSL precompiled script plugins, just apply the `groovy-gradle-plugin` as documented.

> Plugins id's

For Groovy DSL precompiled script plugins you can only follow that convention if I remember correctly. With Kotlin DSL precompiled script plugins you can either follow that naming convention or you can also use package statements inside the script to "properly model" the plugin id.